# How to get all uncheck checkboxes

Tags: php

I know how to get all the check checkboxes by using this code

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if(!empty($_POST['arrsymbols'])){
       $checksymb = $_POST['arrsymbols'];
       foreach ($checksymb as  $selected){
           echo $selected;
       }
    }
}
```

but my problem is how to get all uncheck checkboxes in php. Thank you

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes are not send with the rest of the form data. So you can only go about it the other way around - compare the values that you do get (checked checkboxes) with a list of all checkboxes (like an array with the keys used.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need an array of all checkbox names you have on your page and then you could loop through this array counting how many of the checkboxes are not a key in the array $_POST.
Another solution would be to remove the names from the checkboxes and add them to hidden input which are updated by JS if the checkboxes change.
`jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
  jQuery(this).parent().find("input[type='hidden']").val(jQuery(this).prop("checked"));
}`
This code assumes you have a container for each checkbox containing one checkbox and one hidden input.